# Webview not scroll horizontally in dialog

Tags: android, dialog, horizontal-scrolling

I am loading webview in dialog but it is not scroll Horizontally. Following is my code.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        TwitterDialog fb = new TwitterDialog(this);
        fb.abc();

    }

 class TwitterDialog extends Dialog {
    Context context;
    String url = "https://www.facebook.com";

    public TwitterDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    void abc() {
        LinearLayout mContent = new LinearLayout(context);
        mContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float[] dimensions = new float[] { 400.0f, 500.0f };

        addContentView(mContent, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f), (int) (dimensions[1]
                        * scale + 0.5f)));

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams FILL = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        ScrollView _scroll = new ScrollView(MyMainActivity.this);
        _scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        WebView mWebView = new WebView(context);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebClicent());
        mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
        // _scroll.addView(mWebView);
        mContent.addView(mWebView);

        TwitterDialog.this.show();

    }

}



     private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    // show the web page in webview but not in web browser
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
        }
}
```

I got following output. But It is not scroll Horizontally.

[image: Output]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929047/twitter-authorization-webview-scrollbar-not-working-in-android

Comment: @Scorpion Your Link not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the diamension parameters from the code and let that to be fill_parent both so it will scroll horizontally too

Comment: I am using the same thing for twitter, i have tried your answer and make it fill parent but in that case its just showing me the title. Nothing else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929047/twitter-authorization-webview-scrollbar-not-working-in-android

Comment: Hi, 
I'm trying to do it like this `addContentView(mContent, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));` but it does not work for me. 
Could you please share a code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey add this code to you web view

```
       WebView mWebView = new WebView(context);

       mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebClicent());
       mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
       mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
       mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
       mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Here is the extra code please add it to the above code and check once

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
```